# Updating join table field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base    
has_many :employments, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :users, :through => :employments

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :employments 
has_many :jobs, :through => :employments

class Employment < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :job
belongs_to :user  # Employment has an extra attribute of confirmed ( values are 1 or 0)
```

#### In my view i am trying to update the confirmed fied from 0 to 1 on user click.

```
<%= link_to "Confirm Job", :action => :confirmjob, :id => job.id %>
```

#### In my job Controller I have

```
def confirmjob
  @job = Job.find(params[:id])
  @job.employments.update_attributes(:confirmed, 1)
  flash[:notice] = "Job Confirmed"
  redirect_to :dashboard
end
```

I am sure this is all wrong but I seem to be guessing when it  comes to has_many: through.
How would I do update the confirmed field in a joined table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that a job is assigned to a user by the employment. Thus, updating all employments is not a good idea, as Joel suggests. I would recommend this:

```
class Employment
  def self.confirm!(job)
    employment = Employment.find(:first, :conditions => { :job_id => job.id } )
    employment.update_attribute(:confirmed, true)
  end
end
```

from your controller

```
@job = Job.find(params[:id])
Employment.confirm!(@job)
```

This implies that one job can only be taken by one user.

Comment: I'm not sure if the Employment object already exists, or that it may be nil. If that's the case you might want to extend the `Employment#confirm!` method to handle that as well.

Comment: Ariejan,  

Thanks this worked great. Joel this worked as well except it was updating all the records for that user instead of just for the one job.

Comment: class Employment
    def self.confirm!(job)
    employment = Employment.find(:first, :conditions => { :job_id => job.id } )
    employment.update_attribute(:confirmed, true)
     end
    end
Works, except that i realize i need to pass the current_user id to it as well.
Since my model wont take the session data .  How would i get the current_user option to work
What I need is this.
class Employment
    def self.confirm!(job)
      employment = Employment.find(:first, :conditions => { :job_id => job.id, :user_id => current_user } )
employment.update_attribute(:confirmed, true)
  end
    end

Answer (score 0):

Here is a stab at it (not tested):

```
def confirmjob
  @job = Job.find(params[:id])
  @jobs.employments.each do |e|
    e.update_attributes({:confirmed => 1})
  end
  flash[:notice] = "Job Confirmed"
  redirect_to :dashboard
end
```